# I Want To Write A BASH Script To Find The Current DAY And Then Greet The User As Below:

Tags: bash

For Monday, print Moanday
For Friday, print Friyay
For other days, print Foobar

input date: Fri July 20 10:02:15 IST 2018

Output: Friyay

See My Code Below:

```
day = $(date | cut -d' ' -f1)
if ["$day" == "Monday"];
then
    echo Moanday
elif ["$day" == "Friday"];
then
    echo Friyay
else
    echo Foobar
fi
```

Comment: Paste your script with a shebang first at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Answer (score 1):

With bash, GNU date and an array:

```
d=([1]=Moanday Foobar Foobar Foobar Friday Foobar Foobar)
echo "${d[$(date +%u)]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
 
# From 'man date'
#-----------------------------------------
# %d     day of month (e.g., 01)
# %u     day of week (1..7); 1 is Monday
# %m     month (01..12) 
 #-----------------------------------------

DAY="$(date +%u)"
DATE="$(date +%d)"
MONTH="$(date +%m)"

case $DAY in
  "1")
    echo -e "Moanday"
    ;;
  "2")
    echo -e "Tueasday"
    ;;
  "3")
    echo -e "Wedneasday"
    ;;
  "4")
    echo -e "Thurasday"
    ;;
  "5")
    echo -e "Friday"
    [[ $DATE = "13" ]] && echo "It's friyay the 13th";exit 0
    ;;
  "6")
    echo -e "Saturday"
    ;;
  "7")
    echo -e "Sunday"
    ;;
esac

# Now you can customize this, my example for christmas:
[[ ${MONTH} = "12" && ${DATE} = "24" ]] && echo "It's christmas time" || echo "It's not christmas time :/"
```

Comment: Why use `date|awk '{print $1}'` when you can `date +%A`?

Comment: Sure, edited the example script, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem with the help of "shellcheck.net" as recommended by Cyrus. See below for the correct answer.

```
#!/bin/bash
day=$(date | cut -d' ' -f1)
if [ "$day" == "Monday" ];
then
    echo Moanday
elif [ "$day" == "Friday" ];
then
    echo Friyay
else
    echo Foobar
fi
```

Comment: This script will allways give you "Foobar" since your day command will allways be three characters if you will add all week days as you did, I guess I don't understand the point of this script. :)

Comment: you are right bro @wuseman,  but its not a real live project that i am working on. "am new to LINUX" I am stuck in a test that i was doing. where i am asked to solve this:  WRITE A BASH SCRIPT TO FIND THE CURRENT DAY AND THEN GREET THE USER AS BELOW:    For Monday, print Moanday  For Friday, print Friyay  For other days, print Foobar    input date: Fri July 20 10:02:15 IST 2018    Output: Friyay    This Was How I Met The Terminal Below:    #!/bin/bash    day=$(date | cut -d' ' -f1)    if [ "$day" == "Mon" ]  then    elif [ "$day" == "Fri" ]  then    else    fi    PLS CAN YOU HELP ME SOLVE THIS

Comment: What is the problem, i dont understand I gave you an example already